# ionic 3 - can't create alert inside http request

Tags: http, ionic3, cordova-plugins

So I'm using the native HTTP cordova plugin for my http requests. But I can't seem to wrap my head around a problem where I can't create an alert inside the onFail function. Anyone else experienced this?

The error says:

```
Error in Error callbackId: CordovaHttpPlugin1608257770 : TypeError: Cannot 
read property 'alertCtrl' of undefined
```

Here's how I structured my code:

```
cordova.plugin.http.sendRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login/', options, function(response) {

        try {   //onSuccess
            response.data = JSON.parse(response.data);

            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.token));

          } catch(e) {
            console.error('JSON parsing error');
          }
        },  function(response) {    //onFail
            console.log('403');

            let alert = this.alerts.create({
                title: 'Error',
                subTitle: 'Username/password is invalid!',
                buttons: ['Dismiss']
            });
            alert.present();

        }
    );
```

Here's how my constructor looks like:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            private alerts: AlertController, 
            private http: HTTP, 
            private store: Storage, 
            ) {}
```

What's causing it to not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, because when you create alert in request "this" means httprequest so that hasn't alert class

```
        let alert = this.alerts.create({
            title: 'Error',
            subTitle: 'Username/password is invalid!',
            buttons: ['Dismiss']
        });

cordova.plugin.http.sendRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login/', options, function(response) {

        try {   //onSuccess
            response.data = JSON.parse(response.data);

            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.token));

          } catch(e) {
            console.error('JSON parsing error');
          }
        },  function(response) {    //onFail
            console.log('403');
            alert.present();

        }
    );
```

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm! Can't believe it was caused by such a simple error. Thanks for this you're a lifesaver

Comment: hey would you mind answering another question I posted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962732/ionic-3-cant-store-to-storage-after-http-request