# ionic 3 - can't store to storage after http request

Tags: local-storage, ionic3, storage

I already read the docs regarding Ionic Storage and have already imported what is needed. But still can't seem to get it to work. When I check the localStorage of chrome (I use 'ionic cordova run browser'), it's empty.

Here's my code:

```
cordova.plugin.http.sendRequest('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login/', options, function(response) {

        try {   //onSuccess
            response.data = JSON.parse(response.data);

            this.store.set('token', JSON.stringify(response.data.token));

            this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);

          } catch(e) {
            console.error('JSON parsing error');
          }
        },  function(response) {    //onFail
            console.log('403');
            alert.present();

        }
    );
```

My constructor looks like this:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            private alerts: AlertController, 
            private http: HTTP, 
            private store: Storage, 
            ) {}
```

When I run it, it throws an error and shows 'JSON parsing error' instead of rerouting to HomePage. What am I doing wrong here? Please help

Comment: Learn about promises, and learn how to debug

Comment: @AluanHaddad I just followed what was in the ionic documentation. I just started learning Ionic so my question may seem stupid. Specific answers would be appreciated

Comment: Have you ever used JavaScript before?

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes but only the basics. I'm learning only what is needed in my current Ionic project and trying to debug problems as I code

Comment: Well set breakpoints or log intermediate values. The error is clear: you're trying to parse something as JSON but it is not JSON.